# Gives error DBD::mysql::st fetchrow_array failed: fetch() without execute() only for DELETE statement

Tags: perl, dbi

This isdb connection,

```
$DBH = DBI->connect("dbi:mysql:$DATABASE","$USER","$PASS",{ RaiseError => 1, AutoCommit => 1 }) or die "Connection Error: $DBI::errstr\n";
```

and the following code,

```
$sth=$DBH->prepare("DELETE FROM sample where id=1 ") or warn $DBH->errstr;
$sth->execute or die "can't execute the query: $sth->errstr";
while(@row = $sth->fetchrow_array()){
                $count+=$sth->rows;
}
```

The above code gives me error,

> DBD::mysql::st fetchrow_array failed: fetch() without execute()..

But, when I use `select * from sample where id=1` then it runs. It gives me error only for `delete statement`. Why so?
Help ! Thanx!

Comment: A `delete` statement does not return any row. It only return the number of rows it has deleted.

Comment: @Tensibai Can we count the delete rows

Comment: Try searching the docs, I'm not doing perl but I found [this](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI-1.633/DBI.pm#rows) in the DBI documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do a fetchrow with a delete instruction, it is used only to retrieve data.
What do you think it should return ?

From DBI documentation

> For a non-SELECT statement, execute returns the number of rows affected, if known. If no rows were affected, then execute returns "0E0", which Perl will treat as 0 but will regard as true. Note that it is not an error for no rows to be affected by a statement. If the number of rows affected is not known, then execute returns -1.

You don't need to do a fetchrow, just:

```
my $affected_row = $sth->execute or die "can't execute the query: $sth->errstr";
```

Comment: I wanted to count delete rows number. Wht it does not return affeted rows. Delete also some affet event right.

Comment: I want to count the deleted rows.Is it possible to count the affected rows.

Comment: @Pranay: As said in the doc, a return value of `0E0` means there're no rows affected (ie. no rows were deleted).

Comment: And if rows deleted then It will count the rows or not.

Comment: @Pranay: Yes, it will.